# How can I append two keys from two dictionaries into a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, mergeddictionaries

I'm currently collecting tweets with the Twitter API and want to store them into a CSV file. I want to append key attributes from two dictionaries to the respective user. The data dictionary includes keys of the twitter text, author id, and id. While the users dictionary includes location, name, id, and username keys.
When I try to loop through received tweets, I run this script:

```
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

And get this (not a real tweet):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "author_id": "123",
            "id": "1234",
            "text": "This is a tweet"
        }
    ],
"includes": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                "location": "Earth",
                "name": "example name",
                "username": "example_username"
            },
```

Create a csv file and append:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_response, f)

csvFile = open("data.csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

csvWriter.writerow(['author id', 'location', 'id', 'tweet', 'username'])
csvFile.close()

def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):

    counter = 0

    csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    for tweet in json_response['data']['users']:
        
        # 1. Author ID
        author_id = tweet['author_id']

        # 3. Geolocation
        if ('location' in tweet):   
            location = tweet['location']
        else:
            location = " "

        # 4. Tweet ID
        tweet_id = tweet['id']


        # 8. Tweet text
        text = tweet['text']
    
        username = tweet['user']
        
        # Assemble all data in a list
        res = [author_id,location,tweet,tweet_id,username]
        
        # Append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)
        counter += 1

    csvFile.close()

append_to_csv(json_response, "data.csv")
```

But get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel.py in <module>
----> 1 append_to_csv(json_response, "data.csv")

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel.py in append_to_csv(json_response, fileName)
---> 11     for tweet in json_response['data']['users']:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Could someone help me on how I can "merge" the key attributes from both dictionaries so location and username attributes will also be included with the tweet text and author id when I append to a csv?

I was expecting something like this:

```
author id,id,tweet,location,username
123,1234,This is a tweet,Earth,example_username
```

Comment: That's not what your JSON looks like.  `json_response['data']` is a list, but the `users` element is in `json_response['includes']`.

Comment: I managed to change my script, and added two for loops, one for data and one for includes->users. But now my csv output shows the same name for all the users and ID, but different tweet

Comment: I guess you'll need to ask a new question with your current code.  We can't see your screen.  ;)

Comment: Sorry, I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610478/loop-through-list-of-dictionaries-and-append-to-csv/71610610#71610610