# Loop through list of dictionaries and append to csv

Tags: json, loops, csv

I'm currently trying to collect tweets with the Twitter API. I want to merge two list dictionaries to a csv. The ['data'] list consist of ID and tweet, the second list, ['includes']['users'], consist of username and location. I have tried with two for loops in order to merge these elements, one for ['data'] and one for ['includes']['users']. But I end up having the exact same tweet and ID for every user in my csv output.

`print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))`

My data looks like this (not real tweets):

{"data": [{"author_id": "1234","id": "9999","text": "This is tweet number 1"},{"author_id": "9876","id": "1111","text": "This is another tweet"},],"includes": {"users": [{"id": "9999","location": "Earth","name": "George Huston","username": "George_Huston"},{"id": "1111","name": "Adam Sandler,"username": "adam_sandler"}]

`json_response['includes']['users']`

```
[{'name': 'George Huston','location': 'Earth','id': '9876','username': 'George_Huston'},{'name': 'Adam Sandler', 'id': '9999', 'username': 'adam_sandler}]
```

Creating a csv:

```
# Create file
csvFile = open("data.csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

#Create headers for the data you want to save, in this example, we only want save these columns in our dataset
csvWriter.writerow(['id', 'username', 'text', 'location'])
csvFile.close()
def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):

    #A counter variable
    counter = 0

    #Open OR create the target CSV file
    csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    #Loop through each tweet
    for tweet in json_response['data']:
        
        tweet_id = tweet['id']

        text = tweet['text']

    for element in json_response['includes']['users']:
        
        username = element['username']
    
        if ('location' in tweet):   
            location = element['location']
        else:
            location = " "
        
        # Assemble all data in a list
        res = [tweet_id,username,text,location]
        
        # Append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)
        counter += 1

    # When done, close the CSV file
    csvFile.close()

    # Print the number of tweets for this iteration
    print("# of Tweets added from this response: ", counter)

append_to_csv(json_response, "data.csv")
```

But get this csv output:

id,username,text,location

9999,George_Huston,"This is tweet number 1",

9999,adam_sandler,"This is tweet number 1",

The id, text, location is always the same, while the username is different. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `for tweet in json_response['data']` loop you overwrite `tweet_id` and `text` as the loop goes on. The output you see is whatever they were set to in the last iteration of the loop.

It seems from the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) that you can get usernames from the Tweet Objects as well, without `json_response['includes']['users']` that you used.

Does this do what you want?

```py
# Create file
fileName = 'data.csv'
csvFile = open("data.csv", "w", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

#Create headers for the data you want to save, in this example, we only want save these columns in our dataset
csvWriter.writerow(['id', 'username', 'text', 'location'])
csvFile.close()
def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):

    #A counter variable
    counter = 0

    #Open OR create the target CSV file
    csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    #Loop through each tweet
    for tweet in json_response['data']:
        
        tweet_id = tweet['id']

        text = tweet['text']

        username = tweet['username']

        if ('location' in tweet):   
            location = element['location']
        else:
            location = " "
        
        # Assemble all data in a list
        res = [tweet_id,username,text,location]
        
        # Append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)
        counter += 1

    # When done, close the CSV file
    csvFile.close()

    # Print the number of tweets for this iteration
    print("# of Tweets added from this response: ", counter)

append_to_csv(json_response, "data.csv")
```

Comment: I tried your method, but got this KeyError: 'username'. I also tried for tweet in json_response['data']:
        for element in json_response['includes']['users']:
            tweet_id = tweet['id']
            text = tweet['text']    
            username = element['username']

Comment: for tweet in json_response['data']:
        for element in json_response['includes']['users']:
            tweet_id = tweet['id']
            text = tweet['text']    
            username = element['username'] gives me unique ID, but the same username for each column.

Comment: Could you show what json_response['data'] contains?